# Can not send email by Mailer Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have tried to configure like the tutorials but still can not send email. At the console, it displays the image below:

[image]

I have configured in config file \ environments \ development.rb and production.rb as follows:

```
config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'gmail.com',
    user_name:            'gmail username',
    password:             'password',
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

app\mailers\user_mailer.rb:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def registration_confirmation(user)
    mail(:to => user.email,:subject => "registered")
  end
end
```

app\mailers\application_mailer.rb

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "testonebig@gmail.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

app\controllers\users_controller.rb

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save

        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

It runs without any mistakes have been displayed but when I checked gmail, it's not receive any mail.

Comment: If you are using latest rails version say 4.2, you need to replace .deliver to .deliver_now

Comment: It looks like it's still using `delivery_method = :test` instead of `delivery_method = :smtp` - have you restarted the server since you changed the development.rb file?

Comment: @GauravGupta when i change it to "UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver_now" and add line to config file like this: "
    :openssl_verify_mode => 'none',
    :ssl                    => true,
    :tls                    => true}" it's show "OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError in UsersController#create"

Comment: have you checked spam folder?

Comment: @AmitSharma it is not in the spam folder

Answer (score 1):

Are you providing the correct email and password in your development.rb file?

One more thing:
You are sending email from this id "testonebig@gmail.com", please login with this email in gmail. Just to make sure that everything is ok with your account. May be some kind of issue in authentication with your account.